# awk, sed command to extract filename from lftp log file

Tags: awk, sed

I have an lftp log file with contents below:

```
2020-10-22 09:28:47 /test/scripts/tmp/george1.txt -> sftp://sftpuser@192.168.1.75/test/scripts/tmp/george1.txt 0-5 2.8 KiB/s
2020-10-22 09:28:48 /test/scripts/tmp/george2.txt -> sftp://sftpuser@192.168.1.75/test/scripts/tmp/george2.txt 0-12 6.3 KiB/s
2020-10-22 09:28:49 /test/scripts/tmp/george3.txt -> sftp://sftpuser@192.168.1.75/test/scripts/tmp/george3.txt 0-27 15.4 KiB/s
```

I would like to get it so I only have the date, time, filename and bytes, like so:

```
2020-10-22 09:28:47 george1.txt 5
2020-10-22 09:28:48 george2.txt 12
2020-10-22 09:28:49 george3.txt 27
```

I have an awk, sed script which comes close but I can't figure out how to get ride of the junk in front of the filename:

```
awk '{print $1, $2, $5,$6}' transfer1.log | sed -r -e 's/ [0-9]+-/ /' >
```

transfer_formatted.log.
Results:

```
2020-10-22 09:28:47 sftp://sftpuser@192.168.1.75/test/scripts/tmp/george1.txt 5
2020-10-22 09:28:48 sftp://sftpuser@192.168.1.75/test/scripts/tmp/george2.txt 12
2020-10-22 09:28:49 sftp://sftpuser@192.168.1.75/test/scripts/tmp/george3.txt 27
```

Can someone help me with the sed part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` supports substitutions too:

```sh
$ awk '{sub(/.*\//, "", $5); sub(/[0-9]+-/, "", $6); print $1, $2, $5, $6}' ip.txt
2020-10-22 09:28:47 george1.txt 5
2020-10-22 09:28:48 george2.txt 12
2020-10-22 09:28:49 george3.txt 27
```

Or, assuming the last two columns cannot have `-` character as shown in input sample:

```sh
$ sed -E 's|/.*/([^ ]+) [0-9]+-([0-9]+).*|\1 \2|' ip.txt
2020-10-22 09:28:47 george1.txt 5
2020-10-22 09:28:48 george2.txt 12
2020-10-22 09:28:49 george3.txt 27
```

Comment: Perfect.  both worked as expected.  Thank you so much.

Comment: Sundeep, One last question, is there a way to put OK in front of each line with the sed script, which is the one I am using, So the output will read OK  2020-10-22 09:28:47 george1.txt 5

Comment: @GeorgeAdjei you can use `sed -E 's|/.*/([^ ]+) [0-9]+-([0-9]+).*|\1 \2|; s/^/OK /'` or `sed -E 's|^([^/]+).*/([^ ]+) [0-9]+-([0-9]+).*|OK \1\2 \3|'`

Comment: Thanks a lot Sundeep, you are a master of sed.  It works beautifully.  I also solved it while waiting by piping it to awk: 'awk '{print "OK " $0}' but I like your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
{
  num=split($3,arr,"/")
  split($(NF-2),arr1,"-")
  print $1,$2,arr[num],arr1[2]
}
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                             ##Starting awk program from here.
{
  num=split($3,arr,"/")           ##Splitting 3rd field into array arr with delimiter / and num will have total number of elements in arr.
  split($(NF-2),arr1,"-")         ##Splitting 3rd field from last into array arr1 with delimiter -
  print $1,$2,arr[num],arr1[2]    ##Printing 1st, 2nd field then last item in arr and 2nd item of arr1 here.
}
' Input_file                      ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```